# Is there a way to keep a google doc in suggest mode for specified users while still allowing added script to run?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am working with a school program that requires the students to maintain a journal during a four month independent project. Each student is teamed up with a mentor that will review the journal and provide suggestions and support along the way.

The program sets up each journal as a google doc which is shared to the student (editor permissions), and the mentor and program supervisors (commenter permissions) this is done to ensure that dialogue between mentor and mentee/student is easy to follow.

This year we a adding a set of container bound scripts (because I am new to coding and am not sure how to develop the work into a stand alone or add-on) to the template journal that will be copied and appropriately shared.

The scripts pull up several sidebars with instructions for proper headings, additional assignments, a day and requirement counter, and shortcuts to google forms or other documents shared to the mentee and mentor. they are accessed through a dropdown menu.

The problem I am running into is that the menu shows up as an onOpen trigger which the mentor accounts will not execute because of the commenter mode.

Is there a workaround? Either a different trigger that can be used with the commenter permissions or a way to keep the mentor in suggesting mode even though we change them to editor permissions?

Alternately if a stand alone or add-on process is the only way to go; are there any suggestions for where to start learning the process? Unfortunately the google literature on them still seems a little above my understanding.

Thanks for you patience and help.

Comment: Welcome. Questions about tutorials, learning materials are off-topic in this site but you should ask that in the Google Apps Script community. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/community

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion for tutorial information. Just to confirm I am interpreting correctly you feel there is no in code work around for a container bound script.

Comment: I should said "could" instead of "should", I'm sorry. Anyway, regarding your clarification request, I feel that there isn't a simple code work around.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!  I had a suspicion that was the case, but I did not want to waste time better spent on other projects working up a new system if there was a simple fix. I will look into the resource you suggested. Thanks again for your help.